# SQL count recurring values per week

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've asked the same question for pandas: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330156/pandas-count-recurring-values-per-week)

And now I'm struggling to do the same thing with Big Query SQL. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a `Table` containing dates and ids that are grouped by weeks

items_per_week:

```
date         id    
2022-02-07   1    
             3    
             5    
             4
2022-02-14   2
             1
             3
2022-02-21   9
             10
             1
... 
...
2022-05-16 ....
```

I want to count for each week how much of the id's are repeating from previous week

For example the desired output for the `Table` would be:

```
date        count
2022-02-07  0
2022-02-14  2     # because id 1 and 3 are present in previous week
2022-02-21  1     # because id 1 is present in previous week 
...
```

I tried grouping the id and counting for each id how many are repeating for each date but it didn't work out as planned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing self-join and counting the results:

```
SELECT  t1.date
       ,COUNT(t2.id) as count
FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2
ON  t1.date = DATE_SUB(t2.date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) -- finding previous week
AND t1.id = t2.id -- identifying matching ids
GROUP BY 1
```

Couple assumptions here:

1. **id** is unique per week (i.e you can't have duplicates in a week of 2022-02-07)
2. **date** is iterated over 7 days period (i.e you have one date per week)